# Why is Mikro-orm sending back numbers as strings?

Tags: node.js, orm, mikro-orm

I have a postCount property on a User entity that looks like this:

```
@Property({columnType: 'bigint', nullable: false, default: 0})
postsCount: number;
```

I expect it to come back as a number, but it returns a string.

I've tried using the serializer to convert it to a number, but for my use case I sometimes return a modified user entity from my api (which I believe bypasses the serializer).

Is there another way to return properties as they are defined?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is most likely the expected correct behaviour of the underlying db driver like in the case of [Postgres](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/811)

If you use Postgres you can customize the mapping this way:

```
// Converts floats coming from db to a number
pg.types.setTypeParser(1700, function (val) {
    return parseFloat(val)
})
// Bigints as numbers not as strings
pg.types.setTypeParser(20, 'text', parseInt)
```

where reference to `pg` object can be obtained from import

```
import pg from 'pg'
```

but I don't believe that is the ideal way how to obtain it.